# Power series development for $\frac{1}{4-x^4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have the following problem where I am to find a development using power series for:

$$
\frac{1}{4-x^4}
$$

But I have not grasp the concept of such so I would like assistance in understanding the concept and developing the solution for the given problem.

Comment: You have to indicate around which value of $x$ you want to do this.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier this is all the information that was given.

Comment: It is then reasonable to assume that it is around $0$. But you have to be aware that there is a choice there.

Comment: Do you remember discussing how to sum a geometric series?  You other option is differentiate repeatedly and look for a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Factor out $4$:
$$\smash[t]{\frac{1}{4-x^4}=\frac14\frac{1}{1-\smash[b]{\cfrac{x^4}4}}},$$
and set $t=\dfrac{x^4}4$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have been able to write

$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots$$

Then clearly $a_0=f(0)$. So this already tells you what $a_0$ has to be if there is any hope for such a development: $$a_0=\dfrac{1}{4}$$

Now to get access to $a_1$, consider the derivative of the above expression:

$$f^\prime(x)=a_1+2a_2x+\ldots$$
and iterate :)

Now this is what you would do if the function $f$ was a wild one for which nothing is known yet. But for simple functions like yours, everything is known. The first thing you learn is $$\dfrac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\ldots$$
Via a change of variable you can use this result - as was indicated by Bernard.